# Jenkins Mesos -- Error: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: jenkins, docker, slave, mesos

I am trying to run Jenkins using dynamically generated Docker containers via mesos.

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0120 12:03:47.100700 26501 fetcher.cpp:76] Fetching URI 'http://172.17.20.31:3000/jnlpJars/slave.jar'
I0120 12:03:47.101023 26501 fetcher.cpp:126] Downloading 'http://172.17.20.31:3000/jnlpJars/slave.jar' to '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20150107-091931-521408940-5050-11185-S7/frameworks/20150107-105325-538186156-5050-11332-0354/executors/mesos-jenkins-4bcb550d-bbcf-41ef-9f60-a401f5e4e96d/runs/521ca7ef-1285-4e95-b7bb-09c33faa6286/slave.jar'
I0120 12:03:47.213743 26501 fetcher.cpp:255] Skipped extracting path '/tmp/mesos/slaves/20150107-091931-521408940-5050-11185-S7/frameworks/20150107-105325-538186156-5050-11332-0354/executors/mesos-jenkins-4bcb550d-bbcf-41ef-9f60-a401f5e4e96d/runs/521ca7ef-1285-4e95-b7bb-09c33faa6286/slave.jar'
I0120 12:03:48.002521 26540 exec.cpp:132] Version: 0.21.1
I0120 12:03:48.035147 26543 exec.cpp:206] Executor registered on slave 20150107-091931-521408940-5050-11185-S7
Error: Unable to access jarfile /mnt/mesos/sandbox/slave.jar
```

I have tried:

- manually adding the slave.jar file to the directory specified in the
  Docker container image
- manually adding the slave.jar file to the directory specified on the
  host mesos slave
- removing the existing docker image on the slave to ensure the slaves are pulling the most current docker container.

All with the same result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/jenkinsci/mesos-plugin ? What docker image are you using? One of thefactory/jenkins-mesos or folsomlabs/jenkins-mesos?

Answer (score 1):

By default, --docker_sandbox_directory is set to `/mnt/mesos/sandbox`, which should be a volume in the docker container that maps to `/tmp/mesos/slaves/<slaveId>/frameworks/<frameworkId>/executors/<executorId>/runs/<taskId>/`. Do you see slave.jar in the sandbox through the web UI? How about at the host path listed in the log? Does docker actually mount that sandbox directory into `/mnt/mesos/sandbox/` inside the container? What are the permissions on slave.jar, and what user is trying to access it?

Comment: I was able to get it working by downloading the slave.jar to the host and mounting the host volume to the docker container.

I guess docker was not actually mounting the sandbox directory into the container. Is there some configuration I'm missing for it to dynamically do so?

Comment: If you are using the docker containerizer (--containerizers=docker,mesos), then the sandbox should be mounted in automatically, and the MESOS_SANDBOX env should be set appropriately. Can you do a `docker inspect` and see what volumes are mounted by default?

Comment: I'm having this exact issue and copying the file into the host and setting the 'Container Path' to point at this file in the plugin doesn't seem to work. Are there any other known fixes, or did you come up with something more permanent? @Blanco

Comment: I actually had to specify the Docker container options in Jenkins to mount the specific path in order for it to work for me. What distro are you using for your mesos slaves? I was using CentOS 7. @Sawyer

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue, this was caused by the mesos-slave being run from a docker container. We solved this by mounting this folder into the mesos slave:

`/var/lib/mesos/slave:/var/lib/mesos/slave`

That way, the files written to that directory inside the mesos slave docker also get written to the host drive.